# Yii2: OrderBy with CASE (Order manual)

Tags: mysql, yii2

How can I make a manual ordering?

My  table:

```
table
id | name
1 | inactive
2 | active
3 | archived
```

And the result has to be this order: active, inactive, archived
How can I make in Yii2?

```
Table::find()
->OrderBy(***);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you would use the `field()` function:

```
order by field(name, 'inactive', 'active', 'archived')
```

You can probably implement this in Yii2 using the same function.

Comment: SOLVED: ->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (name, "active", "inactive", "archived")')]);